# How to query tracking number from Magento 1.5?

Tags: magento-1.7, database, magento-1.5

Using **MySQL Workbench** I have a number of **SQL queries** that I use to pull all sorts of information from Magento databases (running on versions 1.7-1.9). I have to pull tracking numbers from a Magento database that is running a legacy version of Magento (1.5). Aside from Mageverse, is there another way to appropriately track the table structure differences across Magento versions? I have checked and it is hard to track down even developer notes and documentation from legacy versions.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, the database of 1.5 should be pretty ok in most parts. The "big" break in v1.x was from 1.4 to 1.5, and I think some important customer data stuff changed from 1.5 to 1.6.

As for the tracking, you should even in v1.5 have the table `sales_flat_shipment_track` that keeps the tracking data. Its `parent_id` has a foreign key for `sales_flat_shipment`, which again has a foreign key in its `order_id` column that leads you to `sales_flat_order`.

Why do you use direct SQL statements after all? Just write a small module to get this information and use collections and objects. They will take care of all the database stuff.